# Error using download.file for web data on PC

Tags: download

## My code:

url <- "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26929842/ug_sch_apps.csv"

download.file(url, destfile = "./ug_sch_apps.csv", method="curl")

list.files( "./ug_sch_apps.csv")
download_date=date()

ug_sch_apps  <- read.csv("./data/ug_sch_apps.csv" ,
                         stringsAsFactors=F)

## My error received:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file './data/ug_sch_apps.csv': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've forgotten the s in https://

AND

use  these code:

`url <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26929842/ug_sch_apps.csv"`

`download.file(url, destfile = "./data/ug_sch_apps.csv", method="curl")`

`ug_sch_apps <- read.csv("./data/ug_sch_apps.csv" , stringsAsFactors=F)`